# Фаза перехвата для событий focus/blur

Tags: javascript, html, css, focus

Прочел статью [Фокусировка](https://learn.javascript.ru/focus-blur)

Там было написано в разделе [События focusin/focusout](https://learn.javascript.ru/focus-blur#sobytiya-focusin-focusout)

> Первое: забавная особенность - focus/blur не всплывают, но передаются вниз на фазе перехвата.
>
> Второе решение: события focusin и focusout – такие же, как и focus/blur, но они всплывают.

В чем отличие фазы перехвата от фазы всплытия?